# PDO for loop issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function that should calculate prices based on quantity.
The function should loop through every order and calculate every product price based on quantity, then should return order total price.
What i'm doing wrong?

```
public function getSumaComanda($cos) {
    $suma = $this->_db->query(sprintf("SELECT (@pretredus:=`pretredus`) AS `pretredus`,(CASE @pretredus WHEN 0 THEN `prettotal` ELSE `pretredus` END) AS `prettotal` , cantitate  FROM comenzi WHERE cos = '%d'", $cos));
    $suma->execute();
    $data_array = $suma->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $count = $this->_db->query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cosuri WHERE id='%d'", $cos));
    $num = $count->fetchColumn();


    for ($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++) {
        $price = $data_array['cantitate'][$x] * $data_array['prettotal'][$x];
        $pret = $pret + $price;
        $pret = number_format($pret, 2, ".", "");

    }

    $rez = $pret;
    return $rez . ' Lei';
}
```

Comment: before asking what you're doing wrong, first say what you think you're doing, what you expect the result to be, what the result *actually* is, and why you think that's wrong. That'll both help us understand your process, and it helps you spot problems possibly even before asking questions by maybe spotting the problem simply by writing out those steps.

Comment: The function should loop through every order and calculate every product price based on quantity.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell everyone on Stackoverflow by editing your post. Walk through those steps I gave you in detail, describing it as if you're writing it to a friend who knows how to program, just nothing about your project. They're going to want more details in order to help you. So do we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn how to basically debug your variables. With using `var_dump($data_array);` you can see, what's in there.

You have to use the numerical index first:

```
$price = $data_array[$x]['cantitate'] * $data_array[$x]['prettotal'];
```

Nevertheless, your second query is useless. You don't have to count the results and can use instead a while-loop:

```
public function getSumaComanda($cos) {
    $suma = $this->_db->query(sprintf("SELECT (@pretredus:=`pretredus`) AS `pretredus`,(CASE @pretredus WHEN 0 THEN `prettotal` ELSE `pretredus` END) AS `prettotal` , cantitate  FROM comenzi WHERE cos = '%d'", $cos));
    $suma->execute();

    while ($data_array = $suma->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $pret += $data_array['cantitate'] * $data_array['prettotal'];
    }

    return number_format($pret, 2, ".", "") . ' Lei';
}
```